# How to add id in div element created through multidimentional array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have function in which i am trying to create a table by extracting data from database. Since the data is extracted automatically from this function i am not able to able to add different css properties like text-alignment (left, center and right) to different columns of the table.

I think i need to add a different id to each column and then add the property using JQuery but since it is a multidimensional loop, i don't know how to add different id to each column.

Can someone help me in solving this query?

```
public function termQuery($val = array()) {
    $query = $this->db->getData('term', '? BETWEEN `min_entry_age` AND `max_entry_age` AND ? BETWEEN `min_sa` AND `max_sa`', $param = array('company_name', 'policy_name'), $operator = array('=', '='), $this->filterValues, $this->data, $this->sort);

    $count = $query->count();

    if ($count) {

        echo '<div class="container"><div class="heading">';
        foreach ($val as $field) {

            $field = str_replace('_', ' ', $field);

            echo '<div class="col">' . ucwords($field) . '</div>';
        }
        echo '</div>';

        foreach ($query->results() as $result) {
            echo '<div class="table-row">';

            foreach ($val as $field) {
                echo '<div class="col">' . $result->$field . '</div>';
            }

            echo '</div>';
        }
        echo '</div> <br>';
        return false;
    }
    echo '<b>No Results found</b><br><br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is in your data?
If you have a ID field in your data then you might be able to do something like this

```
//assume this is the data you extracted from a student table
$data=array(
      array('id'=>'1','name'=>'student1'),
      array('id'=>'2','name'=>'student2')
      );

 //your data will be something like $data={ {1,student1}, {2,student2}}

foreach($data as $student){
    echo "<div id='col".$student['id']."'></div>";
}

//in your html it will produce:
<div id=col1></div><div id=col2></div>
```